# Modify WiFi range

Tags: ad-hoc-network

I need to experiment with ad-hoc multihop. Is there a way to reduce the range of my wifi port while creating an ad-hoc network or later on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your router or the terminal you are serving the ad-hoc network has adjustable power output (some advanced wireless cards or DD-WRT have that), you can try dialing down the power to reduce the range. Alternatively, encase the antennae (if there's one) in aluminium foil and see if that reduces range. or remove the antennae totally.